# google mock - can I call EXPECT_CALL multiple times on same mock object?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

If I call `EXPECT_CALL` twice on the same mock object in the same `TEST_F` . . . what happens?

Are the expectations appended to the mock object or does the second call erase the effects of the first call?

I found [The After Clause](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#the-after-clause-afterclause) which appears to imply that multiple calls to same mock + EXPECT_CALL are allowed.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong, with some right things about it. I've commented under it to explain. Here's a more thorough and correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034633/google-mock-can-i-call-expect-call-multiple-times-on-same-mock-object/60905880#60905880

Comment: Update: @luantkow has updated his answer and it looks good now. For additional insight beyond that see the super long answer I have posted here too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you can call `EXPECT_CALL` on the same mock object multiple times. As long as you assure that all `EXPECT_CALL` were called before the mocked methods were actually used. Otherwise your test will rely on undefined behavior. From [ForDummies](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests):

> Important note: gMock requires expectations to be set before the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is undefined. In particular, you mustn't interleave EXPECT_CALL()s and calls to the mock functions.

How multiple calls will be handled? The documentation is really straightforward. From [ForDummies](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#using-multiple-expectations-multiexpectations):

> By default, when a mock method is invoked, Google Mock will search the
> expectations in the reverse order they are defined, and stop when an
> active expectation that matches the arguments is found (you can think
> of it as "newer rules override older ones.").

Let's consider what this means for the gMock user, by checking some examples. I assume that we have a file with following header:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace ::testing;

struct SomeMock
{
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(foo, void(int));
};
```

The simplest example of passing test that calls `EXPECT_CALL` multiple times:

```
TEST(Examples, DifferentArgumentsGoingToBeOk)
{
    SomeMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); // exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(5)).Times(1); // exp#2
 
    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(5); // call#2
}
```

The tests works intuitively:

- `call#1` does not match with `exp#2` so `exp#1` is tried and matches.
- `call#2` matches with `exp#2`.

Both calls matched exactly once, thus they are considered satisfied and the test passes.

The tricky part starts when multiple `EXPECT_CALL` are able to match the call. Let's consider the following example:

```
TEST(Examples, TheSameArgumentsGoingToFail) // Test fails!
{
    SomeMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); //exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); //exp#2
 
    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(4); // call#2
}
```

- The `call#1` matches the `exp#2`. gMock stops at first matched expectation, it won't check the `exp#1` at all.
- The `call#2` matches the `exp#2`. Again the `exp#1` does not have chance to be matched.

As a result the test fails as the `exp#2` gets matched twice instead of once and `exp#1` is not matched at all. All that is printed in the test output:

```
/tmp/so/main.cpp:26: Failure // exp#2
Mock function called more times than expected - returning directly.
    Function call: foo(4)
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: called twice - over-saturated and active
/tmp/so/main.cpp:25: Failure // exp#1
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Also, it is important, that adding new expectancy won't disable or remove old ones. They are still able to fail your test!

```
TEST(Examples, NewExpectCallDoesNotEraseThePreviousOne) // Test fails!
{
    SomeMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); // exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(2); // exp#2
 
    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(4); // call#2
}
```

Both `call#1` and `call#2` matches the `exp#2`. As a result the `exp#2` is satisfied, but the test will fail as `exp#1` was not matched enough times.

If for some reason, you need to write a test like `TheSameArgumentsGoingToFail`, you can use a number of techniques to prevent `exp#2` from matching second time. Please refer to the documentation [InSequence usage](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#ordered-vs-unordered-calls-orderedcalls), [RetiresOnSaturation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#all-expectations-are-sticky-unless-said-otherwise-stickyexpectations):

```
TEST(Examples, InSequenceExample)
{
    SomeMock mock;

    Sequence seq;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1).InSequence(seq); //exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1).InSequence(seq); //exp#2

    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(4); // call#2
}

TEST(Examples, InSequenceExampleSecondApproach)
{
    SomeMock mock;

    InSequence seq;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); //exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); //exp#2

    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(4); // call#2
}

TEST(Examples, RetiresOnSaturationExample)
{
    SomeMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); //exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1).RetiresOnSaturation(); //exp#2

    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(4); // call#2
}

TEST(Examples, AfterExample)
{
    SomeMock mock;

    auto& exp1 = EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1); //exp#1
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1).After(exp1); //exp#2

    mock.foo(4); // call#1
    mock.foo(4); // call#2
}
```

Comment: You should replace `EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4));` with `EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4)).Times(1);` to make it explicitly obvious that this `EXPECT_CALL` is setting the mocked function to be expected to be called once. You are letting the natural rules take over which implicitly set `.Times()` to `1`. See the paragraph here which begins with "[If Times() is omitted, the cardinality is assumed to be](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#setting-expectations-expectcall)"...

Comment: You said: **In the following file the test `TheSameArgumentsGoingToFail` will fail as the second expectation will be matched twice and the first one will not be matched at all.** I downvoted this answer because this misattributes the fact that you have `EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4));` twice as the reason it will fail. This is *not* true. It *is* true that "the second expectation will be matched twice & the first one will not be matched at all," however. The real reason is that if you don't specify the `.Times()` number, gmock uses the rules in my comment above to assume it, & in this case it is 1.

Comment: So, the first `EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4));` is ignored, and only the 2nd one is used, but the 2nd one doesn't specify the `.Times()` value, so gmock assumes it to be 1 in this case, following the rules in the link in my comment above, and then when you call `mock.foo(4)` the 2nd time, it violates the `.Times(1)` specifier, and then the test fails. *That's* why it fails. If you fix your answer I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Do I understand correctly that you downvoted my answer because I havn't explicitly used `Times` in my examples, while being aware that assuming 1 (which was my intent) is documented behavior? I've edited my answer, as: it does not change my answer at all; it seemed to be important for you and `explicit is better than implicit`. Still, I consider downvoting my answer due to that as nitpicking.

Comment: I've read the section you mentioned several times and it did not helped me understand what exactly is wrong with my answer. The code example that shows the mistake could be very helpful here. I am quite confident that I may present a code that proves your understanding is not sound, check the 'theTestWillFailWhenOnlyLastExpectancyWasSatisfied' in https://gist.github.com/lukant/376df8c49a3aba8179879fadcea77dea with regard to 'only the last one set will have any effect'. If you believe that you can improve my answer and you are certain that your understanding is correct, feel free to do so.

Comment: I've edited your answer & upvoted it. I was missing your point and so I had to make more changes than anticipated. I fully see your point now as your point is 100% correct, though. I still think you were missing my point, but it is now stated clearly in your answer (assuming you leave my edit intact) as `2. Because Times(1) expects one call but mock.foo(4) is called twice.` In case anyone wants to play with this, I've created this project here to tinker with: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_gtest_practice. Watching the test errors and output really helped me figure it all out.

Comment: Your latest changes are good. Upvoted. There was a brief downvote I did between you removing my edit and you adding your latest changes, but your latest changes look good, and are exactly in accordance with my observations and testing as well. I agree with your answer. Thanks. The only part I haven't verified are your last 4 tests at the very bottom, which you are saying will all *pass*, correct?

Comment: I just tested all 4 of the `TEST()`s at the bottom of your answer. They all pass. Thanks for adding those. They are a very useful starting point for learning about those concepts. For anyone else who wants to try running any of these tests too, here's my project: [eRCaGuy_gtest_practice](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_gtest_practice). Test the last 4 tests of this answer with this command: `time bazel test --test_output=all --test_arg=--gtest_color=yes //:gmock_test3`.

Comment: Is this the same for ON_CALL, can we have multiple definition to same mock method?

Comment: @PorottayumBeefum yes, we can have multiple definition. Just as with `EXPECT_CALL`, the last matching `ON_CALL` definition will be used. See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#setting-the-default-actions-for-a-mock-method for more information.

Answer (score 31):

*A link to this answer [as an article in my GitHub repo](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/googletest/insights.md) can be found in Google's gtest documentation here: [googletest/docs/community_created_documentation.md](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/community_created_documentation.md).*

---

*All of the below code was tested with Googletest/Googlemock [v1.10.0](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases), which was released 3 Oct. 2019.*

If you'd like to run tests for yourself but don't have googletest or googlemock set up on your system, [here's a bare-bones project I created](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_gtest_practice) to get it up and running quickly on Ubuntu. Go clone it and play with it yourself. It may act as a starting point to help you get it running on Mac or Windows as well.

This is a really important question, so I feel compelled to have a hack at it.

### The nuances:

Let me start by saying that Google Mock (gmock) is *nuanced*. That means there are lots of subtleties to understand, and this is difficult. Even the documentation is a bit scattered, and you kind of need to carefully read and study *it all* to really grasp some or even most of these nuances, since they don't do a good job of repeating certain important points in each of the documents. So, here is all of the official documentation: if you're doing this for work, tell your supervisor you are going to set aside several days to carefully go through the gtest and gmock documentation and to practice examples to get a strong grasp on it.

### The documentation:

*As you read and study the below documentation, save each one as (print it to) a PDF, then use [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) for free on Windows, Mac, or Linux, to edit, take notes in, and highlight or underline the PDF as you go. This way you have notes of the most important things you need to remember. See my `*_GS_edit.pdf` PDFs [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/googletest/gtest) and [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/googletest/gmock) for examples of taking notes and marking up PDFs that I have done as I've learned Google Test and Google Mock.*

**Official Google Documentation:**

1. gtest: it's all in this folder: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest/docs. The key documents to study, in this order probably, are the:

   1. **primer**
   2. **FAQ**
   3. **samples** (look at and carefully study the source code for *at least* the first 3 samples)
   4. advanced
2. gmock: it's all in this folder: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock/docs. The key documents to study, in this order probably, are the:

   1. **for dummies**
   2. **cook book**
   3. **cheat sheet** - this is the best one-stop-shop or "summary of gmock rules" of all of the docs, but lacks some things that are even spelled out explicitly in (and only in) the "for dummies" manual that you will need in addition to this doc.
   4. **FAQ**
   5. **for dummies** <-- yes, AGAIN! AFTER doing and attempting to write a bunch of tests and mocks, then *come back* and re-read this document again! It will make sooo much more sense the 2nd time around after putting gtest and gmock principles into practice yourself first.

### Some subtle rules to remember in general:

1. > Remember that the test order is undefined, so your code can't depend on a test preceding or following another

   Source: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite
2. > **Important note:** gMock requires expectations to be set **before** the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is **undefined**. In particular, you mustn't interleave `EXPECT_CALL()`s and calls to the mock functions

   Source: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests

   New wording:

   > **Important note:** gMock requires expectations to be set **before** the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is **undefined.** Do not alternate between calls to `EXPECT_CALL()` and calls to the mock functions, and do not set any expectations on a mock after passing the mock to an API.

---

### The answers:

#### Question 1: "If I call `EXPECT_CALL` twice on the same mock object in the same `TEST_F` . . . what happens?"

A: First off, whether your're using the `TEST()` macro or the `TEST_F()` macro in this case makes no difference. The `TEST()` macro simply expands into a class which publicly inherits from the `::testing::Test` class, and the `TEST_F()` macro simply expands into a class which inherits from your test fixture class (the first parameter to `TEST_F()`), which must publicly inherit from the `::testing::Test` class.

Many `EXPECT_CALL`s can be called on the same mock object (mock class), from general to specific, as follows:

**The 3 rules of multiple `EXPECT_CALL`s on the same mock object:**
From most generic --> most specific (AKA: "outer" --> "inner" scope).

1. **You can have *at least* one `EXPECT_CALL` per mock method:** One mock class can have many mocked methods, so each method may have one or more `EXPECT_CALL`s configuring the expected interaction with that method. Therefore, a mock class can have *at least* one `EXPECT_CALL` per method.
2. **You *shouldn't have more than one* `EXPECT_CALL` per matcher signature on a single mock method:** (Read more on this in Rule 3 below). Each mock method has many different parameter *values* that can be passed in, so you can have *up to* one `EXPECT_CALL` per matcher signature (possible parameter value or combination of values, in the event of multiple input parameters). This means each mock method can have potentially many *thousands* or even *millions or billions* of *valid and unique* `EXPECT_CALL`s attached to it, each matching a different set of "matchers", or input parameters to the mocked method. For example, this is perfectly valid:

   ```
    // Each `EXPECT_CALL()` in this example has a different and 
    // unique "matcher" signature, so every `EXPECT_CALL()` will
    // take effect for its matching parameter signature when
    // `myMockMethod()` is called.
    //                                    v--matchers
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(1));
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(2));
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(3));
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(4));
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(5));
    ...
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(1000));
   ```

   In particular, the above `EXPECT_CALL`s each specify that a call to `myMockMethod()` with that matching signature must occur *exactly 1 time*. That's because the [cardinality rules](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#cardinalities-how-many-times-will-it-be-called) in this case dictate than an implicit `.Times(1)` is present on each of those `EXPECT_CALL`s, even though you don't see it written.

   To specify that you want a given `EXPECT_CALL` to mach *any* input value for a given parameter, use the `::testing::_` matcher, like this:

   ```
    using ::testing::_;

    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_));
   ```
3. **Don't have *duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s with the same matcher signature* on the same mock method, but *multiple* `EXPECT_CALL`s with *overlapping/overriding* (but NOT duplicate) matcher signatures on the same mock method are OK:** If you attach more than one `EXPECT_CALL` to the same *matching values*, only *the last one set* will have any effect. See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#using-multiple-expectations-multiexpectations), [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#all-expectations-are-sticky-unless-said-otherwise-stickyexpectations), and [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#performing-different-actions-based-on-the-arguments), for instance. This means if you have two or more `EXPECT_CALL`s with duplicate matcher signatures (the same parameters passed to the mock method), then ONLY THE LAST ONE WILL EVER GET ANY CALLS.

   Therefore, your test will ALWAYS FAIL except in the unusual case that all `EXPECT_CALL`s except the last one have a `.Times(0)` value, specifying that they will *never* be called, as indeed this is the case: the last `EXPECT_CALL` will match all of the calls for these matchers and all duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s above it will have *no* matching calls! Here is an example of a test which will **always fail** as a result of this behavior. This is the main behavior that @luantkow focuses on [in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035118/4561887).

   ```
    using ::testing::_;

    // Notice they all have the same mock method parameter "matchers"
    // here, making only the last `EXPECT_CALL()` with this matcher
    // signature actually match and get called. Therefore, THIS TEST
    // WILL ***ALWAYS FAIL***, since EXPECT_CALL #1 expects to get 
    // called 1 time but is NEVER called, #2 through #1006, inclusive,
    // all expect to get called 2 times each but all of them are NEVER
    // called, etc.! Only #1007 is ever called, since it is last and
    // therefore always matches first.          
    //                                    v--matchers
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(1); // EXPECT_CALL #1
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(2); // EXPECT_CALL #2
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(2); // EXPECT_CALL #3
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(2); // EXPECT_CALL #4
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(2); // EXPECT_CALL #5
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(2); // EXPECT_CALL #6
    // ... duplicate the line just above 1000 more times here
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(3); // EXPECT_CALL #1007
   ```

   This weird exception, however, makes the test valid simply by setting all duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s, *except for the last one*, to have a `.Times(0)` cardinal setting:

   ```
    using ::testing::_;

    // Notice they all have the same mock method parameter "matchers"
    // here, making only the last `EXPECT_CALL()` with this matcher
    // signature actually match and get called. However, since all previous
    // `EXCEPT_CALL` duplicates are set to `.Times(0)`, this test is valid
    // and can pass.          
    //                                    v--matchers
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(0); // EXPECT_CALL #1
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(0); // EXPECT_CALL #2
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(0); // EXPECT_CALL #3
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(0); // EXPECT_CALL #4
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(0); // EXPECT_CALL #5
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(0); // EXPECT_CALL #6
    // ... duplicate the line just above 1000 more times here
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(3); // EXPECT_CALL #1007
   ```

   Here, only `EXPECT_CALL` #1007 (the very last `EXPECT_CALL`) will ever match a call to `myMockMethod()`, and `Times(3)` will be in effect. Since all duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s above this one will NEVER MATCH AND GET CALLED, since they are never reached, tests with duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s for a given matcher would ALWAYS FAIL for any `.Times()` value other than `.Times(0)` for all non-last-place duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s.

   This effect of making later matchers have the ability to override earlier matchers is *intentional* and part of the Googlemock design, as it allows you to create a very useful kind of hierarchy of expected calls, based on value passed to the mock method, like this:

   ```
    using ::testing::_;

    // Most general matchers first (_ matches any input value)
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(_)).Times(1);
    // More specific matchers next, to override the more general matcher 
    // above if they match
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(7)).Times(2);
    EXPECT_CALL(myMockClass, myMockMethod(5)).Times(4);
   ```

   The various google documents say that matching `EXPECT_CALL`s are searched for in *reverse order*, from *bottom to top*. So, if `myMockMethod(8)` is called, it will be checked against the last `EXPECT_CALL` for this method, which is looking for `myMockMethod(5)`. That doesn't match, so it goes up one and checks against `myMockMethod(7)`. That doesn't match, so it goes up one and checks against `myMockMethod(_)`. This matches! So, it counts as the one call authorized by the `Times(1)` cardinal value.

   So, what you've defined above is this: we expect `myMockMethod(5)` to be called 4 times, `myMockMethod(7)` to be called 2 times, and `myMockMethod(anything_other_than_5_or_7)` to be called 1 time. For more reading on this topic, see my other answer here: [google mock - how to say "function must be called ONCE with a certain parameter but ok to be called many times with different parameters"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249293/google-mock-how-to-say-function-must-be-called-once-with-a-certain-parameter/60896373#60896373).

**Key summary:** the main point to remember regarding the question "Can I call `EXPECT_CALL` multiple times on same mock object?", is this: you can only call `EXPECT_CALL` multiple times on the same mock object *and method* if the matchers (arguments specified to be passed to the mocked method) are *different* for each `EXPECT_CALL`. That is, of course, unless you set `.Times(0)` on all but the last duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`, which makes them useless, so just remember instead to not have duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s with the same matchers.

That fully answers this question.

---

#### Question 2: "Are the expectations appended to the mock object or does the second call erase the effects of the first call?"

The above description answers this question as well. Essentially, the `EXPECT_CALL` expectations do NOT override the effects of any `EXPECT_CALL`s before them, **unless** the matchers (values specified to be passed to the mock methods) are identical or overlapping, in which case only the *last* `EXPECT_CALL` will ever get called at all, as it is always reached before the others in the matching sequence. Therefore, don't have duplicate `EXPECT_CALL`s with the same matchers on a given mocked method or else you could be inadvertently forcing the test to *always fail*, since the above `EXPECT_CALL`s will never get called. This is discussed at length in Question 1 above.

Again, for more reading on this topic, read above, and see my other answer here: [google mock - how to say "function must be called ONCE with a certain parameter but ok to be called many times with different parameters"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249293/google-mock-how-to-say-function-must-be-called-once-with-a-certain-parameter/60896373#60896373).

---

#### Question 3: Can I call `EXPECT_CALL` to set some expectations on a mock method, call the mock method, then call `EXPECT_CALL` on the method again to change the expectations, then call the mock method again?

This question wasn't even *explicitly* asked by the OP, but the only reason I found this page is because I was searching for this answer for many hours and couldn't find it. My Google search was "[gmock multiple expect_call](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00e6UHbLaPL3B5-042GF9KQRt9QhA%3A1585335955965&ei=k05-Xq7LOri10PEPwL-ciA8&q=gmock%20multiple%20expect_call&oq=gmock%20multiple%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l3j0i22i30l7.2786111.2787311..2789283...0.4..0.305.1339.0j8j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.e3x6IuEQpb0)." Therefore, others asking this question will also fall on this page and need a conclusive answer.

A: NO, you can NOT do this! Although it may *seem to work in testing*, according to Google, it produces *undefined behavior*. See general rule #2 above!

> "**Important note:** gMock requires expectations to be set **before** the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is **undefined**. In particular, you mustn't interleave `EXPECT_CALL()`s and calls to the mock functions" (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests)

See also my answer here: [Interleaving `EXPECT_CALL()`s and calls to the mock functions is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467271/4561887).

Therefore, this is NOT ALLOWED!:

```
// EXAMPLE OF A BAD TEST THAT MAY SEEM TO WORK BUT IS RELYING ON *UNDEFINED* BEHAVIOR!
// The goal is to ensure that `myMockMethod()` is only called 2x the first time by 
// `myOtherFunc()`, 3x the second time, and 0x the last time.

// Google states: "**Important note:** gMock requires expectations to be set 
// **before** the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is **undefined**. 
// In particular, you mustn't interleave `EXPECT_CALL()`s and calls to the mock functions"
// (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests)

using ::testing::_;

TEST_F(MyTestFixture, MyCustomTest) 
{
    // `myMockMethod()` should be called only 2x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
    // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
    EXPECT_CALL(MyMockClass, myMockMethod(_, _))
        .Times(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myOtherFunc();
    }

    // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR BEGINS HERE: you can't interleave calls to `EXPECT_CALL` with 
    // calls to the mocked functions (in this case: `myMockMethod()`,
    // which is called by `myOtherFunc()`).

    // THEN `myMockMethod()` should be called 3x here by `myOtherFunc()`
    EXPECT_CALL(MyMockClass, myMockMethod(_, _))
        .Times(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myOtherFunc();
    }

    // LAST, `myMockMethod()` should be called 0x here by `myOtherFunc()`
    EXPECT_CALL(MyMockClass, myMockMethod(_, _))
        .Times(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myOtherFunc();
    }
}
```

So, what's a valid solution here? Well, if you can break this test up into 3 different, independent tests, just do that! But, what if these 3 tests are interconnected in such a way you cannot separate them? Example: you are trying to test a throttling function which throttles print output to only once per second, for instance, even if you try to print more often that that per second. Well, in this case there are some work-arounds.

First, let's review: per the [Google Mock Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#setting-expectations-expectcall), here are the ways to configure an `EXPECT_CALL()`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock-object, method (matchers)?)
     .With(multi-argument-matcher)  ?
     .Times(cardinality)            ?
     .InSequence(sequences)         *
     .After(expectations)           *
     .WillOnce(action)              *
     .WillRepeatedly(action)        ?
     .RetiresOnSaturation();        ?
```

> For each item above, `?` means it can be used at most once, while `*` means it can be used any number of times.

We need to use the `.WillRepeatedly(action)` option with an `action` which [produces side effects](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#side-effects) or [calls a function, functor, or lambda](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#using-a-function-functor-or-lambda-as-an-action) as an action.

Here are some work-arounds to safely and correctly perform the above test which had undefined behavior. *If you want to see the best approach first, just jump straight down to #3 below:*

1. **Use `Assign(&variable, value)`.** In this particular case, this is a bit hacky, but it does work properly. For a simpler test case you may have, this might be the perfect way to do what you need. Here's a viable solution:

   Side note: an error output I got while trying to run a gmock test said:

   > `.Times()` cannot appear after `.InSequence()`, `.WillOnce()`, `.WillRepeatedly()`, or `.RetiresOnSaturation()`,

   ...so it turns out we don't need to (and we are not even *allowed to*) specify `.Times(::testing::AnyNumber())` here. Instead, gmock will figure it out automatically, according to [these cardinality rules](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#cardinalities-how-many-times-will-it-be-called), since we are using `.WillRepeatedly()`:

   > **If you omit `Times()`, gMock will infer the cardinality for you.** The rules are easy to remember:

   > - If **neither** `WillOnce()` nor `WillRepeatedly()` is in the `EXPECT_CALL()`, the inferred cardinality is `Times(1)`.
   > - If there are *n* `WillOnce()`'s but **no** `WillRepeatedly()`, where *n* >= 1, the cardinality is `Times(n)`.
   > - If there are *n* `WillOnce()`'s and **one** `WillRepeatedly()`, where *n* >= 0, the cardinality is `Times(AtLeast(n))`.

   *This technique has actually been tested and proven to work on real code:*

   ```
    using ::testing::_;
    using ::testing::Assign;

    TEST_F(MyTestFixture, MyCustomTest) 
    {
        bool myMockMethodWasCalled = false;

        EXPECT_CALL(MyMockClass, myMockMethod(_, _))
            // Set `myMockMethodWasCalled` to true every time `myMockMethod()` is called with
            // *any* input parameters!
            .WillRepeatedly(Assign(&myMockMethodWasCalled, true));

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 1st sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called only 2x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();

            if (i < 2)
            {
                EXPECT_TRUE(myMockMethodWasCalled);
                myMockMethodWasCalled = false;        // reset
                EXPECT_FALSE(myMockMethodWasCalled);  // ensure reset works (sanity check)
            }
            else
            {
                EXPECT_FALSE(myMockMethodWasCalled);
            }
        }

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 2nd sub-test

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called only 3x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();

            if (i < 3)
            {
                EXPECT_TRUE(myMockMethodWasCalled);
                myMockMethodWasCalled = false;        // reset
                EXPECT_FALSE(myMockMethodWasCalled);  // ensure reset works (sanity check)
            }
            else
            {
                EXPECT_FALSE(myMockMethodWasCalled);
            }
        }

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 3rd sub-test

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called 0x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
            EXPECT_FALSE(myMockMethodWasCalled);
        }
    }
   ```
2. **Use `InvokeWithoutArgs(f)` with a global counter variable and a global counter function.** This works great, and is much easier to use and more versatile than the previous approach! Note that you could also migrate this global function and variable to be inside your test fixture class as well if you wanted, which would clean it up a bit.

   *This technique has actually been tested and proven to work on real code:*

   ```
    using ::testing::_;
    using ::testing::InvokeWithoutArgs;

    static uint32_t callCounter = 0;
    static void incrementCallCounter()
    {
        callCounter++;
    }

    TEST_F(MyTestFixture, MyCustomTest)
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(MyMockClass, myMockMethod(_, _))
            // Set gmock to increment the global `callCounter` variable every time 
            // `myMockMethod()` is called with *any* input parameters!
            .WillRepeatedly(InvokeWithoutArgs(incrementCallCounter));

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 1st sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called only 2x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        callCounter = 0; // ensure this is zero BEFORE you start the test!
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
        }
        EXPECT_EQ(callCounter, 2);

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 2nd sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called only 3x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        callCounter = 0; // ensure this is zero BEFORE you start the test!
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
        }
        EXPECT_EQ(callCounter, 3);

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 1st sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called 0x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        callCounter = 0; // ensure this is zero BEFORE you start the test!
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
        }
        EXPECT_EQ(callCounter, 0);
    }
   ```
3. **[BEST TECHNIQUE] Use `InvokeWithoutArgs(f)` with a *local* counter variable and a simple lambda function!** This works great, and is much easier to use and more versatile than the 1st approach, while avoiding the global variable and additional global function of the 2nd approach. It is for sure my favorite way to handle this, and works extremely well.

   *This technique has actually been tested and proven to work on real code:*

   ```
    using ::testing::_;
    using ::testing::InvokeWithoutArgs;

    TEST_F(MyTestFixture, MyCustomTest)
    {
        uint32_t callCounter;

        EXPECT_CALL(MyMockClass, myMockMethod(_, _))
            // Use a lambda function to set gmock to increment `callCounter` every 
            // time `myMockMethod()` is called with *any* input parameters!
            .WillRepeatedly(InvokeWithoutArgs([&callCounter](){ callCounter++; }));

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 1st sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called only 2x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        callCounter = 0; // ensure this is zero BEFORE you start the test!
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
        }
        EXPECT_EQ(callCounter, 2);

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 2nd sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called only 3x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        callCounter = 0; // ensure this is zero BEFORE you start the test!
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
        }
        EXPECT_EQ(callCounter, 3);

        // Do any necessary setup here for the 1st sub-test 

        // Test that `myMockMethod()` is called 0x here by `myOtherFunc()`,
        // despite calling `myOtherFunc()` repeatedly
        callCounter = 0; // ensure this is zero BEFORE you start the test!
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            myOtherFunc();
        }
        EXPECT_EQ(callCounter, 0);
    }
   ```

If you think this whole answer should be added as a stand-alone file among the Gmock docs (I propose we do this), click the github issue link just below and upvote it.

### Practice using gtest/gmock:

1. Use this project to practice writing and testing your own google tests and google mocks. This is also a good demo of how to get a new project up and running with Google's [Bazel build system](https://bazel.build/): https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_gtest_practice.

### Related:

1. GitHub issue I opened to request to add this answer as a standalone document in their official documentation. If you agree, please go here and upvote this issue: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2775
2. [google mock - how to say "function must be called ONCE with a certain parameter but ok to be called many times with different parameters"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249293/google-mock-how-to-say-function-must-be-called-once-with-a-certain-parameter/60896373#60896373)
3. [Google Mock: multiple expectations on same function with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743236/google-mock-multiple-expectations-on-same-function-with-different-parameters/5899945)
4. [google mock - how to say "function must be called ONCE with a certain parameter but ok to be called many times with different parameters"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249293/google-mock-how-to-say-function-must-be-called-once-with-a-certain-parameter)
5. [Interleaving EXPECT_CALL()s and calls to the mock functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089204/interleaving-expect-calls-and-calls-to-the-mock-functions)

   1. [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467271/4561887)

Comment: Those "todo" mean you haven't finished writing the answer yet?

Comment: Yes, got interrupted by kids. Will come back to it later--hopefully tonight.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica, done! I've just added 3 large examples to the bottom of my answer and fulfilled all `todo`s. If you find this answer useful, I'd appreciate an upvote. Thanks. This has been a ton of learning for me.

Comment: Absolutely, it's an awesome answer! You've also shown me that I've been using multiple EXPECT_CALLs in a wrong way. I'm not sure this should be a standalone intro, but it should definitely be integrated in the official docs. I've created a GitHub account just to vote for it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After playing around a lot today in my [sandbox test project here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_gtest_practice), I've discovered some glaring things that are wrong in my answer. I'm going to fix them ASAP--the biggest one being my claim that you can have infinite `EXPECT_CALL`s with the same matchers. This is wrong. Any more than one per matcher throws test errors & always fails the tests, since earlier `EXPECT_CALL`s expect to have calls, but never get them since the later matching `EXPECT_CALL`s always match instead. I've also edited @luantkow's answer to make this clear.

Comment: My answer is all fixed and correct now! My main changes were in my Rule #3 of "The 3 rules of multiple EXPECT_CALLs on the same mock object". There were some more subtleties going on there that I had to test repeatedly and  observe using [my test project here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_gtest_practice).

Comment: This question answered our problems

Comment: This answer highlights that gtest is particulary not obvious to use :O

Comment: Many thanks for this EPIC answer!

Answer (score 9):

Another useful technique (which is also shown in the For Dummies guide) is to only write one `EXPECT_CALL` but chain off multiple sets of actions indicating the expected results.  For example:

```
SomeMock mock;

EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(4))
    .WillOnce(Return(16))
    .WillOnce(Return(42))
    .WillOnce(Throw(MyException()));
```

This expects three calls to the method with the same parameters, and will return the specified values the first two times and then throw an exception on the third call.

This is often easier to understand than using multiple `EXPECT_CALL` and `RetiresOnSaturation` or other techniques.

You can use this with void methods as well; you just need to use `DoDefault` or some more interesting action in place of `Return`.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't need to specify .Times(3) here.. since the default is Times(1).

Comment: Maybe it's because it can let people think that the call will be done 3x3 times.. :O